# Keep running Dataproc Master node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to keep the master machine running in Dataproc? Every time that I run the job after a while (~1 hour), I see the master node is stopped. It is not a real issue since I would easily start it again but I would like to know if there is a way to keep it awake.

A possible way that occurs to me is to do a schedule job in the master machine, but want to know if there is more official way to achieve this.

Comment: The master should not be stopped from being idle. Can you check your project's activity feed and look for details around what source called the stop instance on your master?

Comment: I checked in the activity. It was stopped by Compute Engine default service account.

Comment: I'd try to go through the logs leading up to the time period the shutdown happened. Do you have any scripts that call shutdown/restart/halt? I just verified that letting a cluster idle for 1hr+ doesn't have an automatic shutdown.

Comment: Thanks! I have created another cluster and it seems this is not happening. I think this is because my cluster was created following some tutorial and there are some initialization actions.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what initialization did you find that caused this problem? I'm having the same issue but can't figure out the reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataproc does not stop any cluster nodes (including master) when they are idle.

You need to check if you have some kind of automation or user that can do this on your end.

Comment: I see that there are some Initialization files in my cluster. I created the cluster following some tutorial and not sure why these files are there. But I think you are right and the issue should be on my end.

Comment: @user9721331 did you find where the problem was? I'm experiencing the same issue...

Comment: For reference, relevant issue when using Datalab initialization action:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583747/how-to-keep-google-dataproc-master-running