# How to keep Google Dataproc master running?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I created a cluster on Dataproc and it works great. However, after the cluster is idle for a while (~90 min), the master node will automatically stops. This happens to every cluster I created. I see there is a similar question here: [Keep running Dataproc Master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197428/keep-running-dataproc-master-node#comment97832364_53197428)

It looks like it's the initialization action problem. However the post does not give me enough info to fix the issue. Below are the commands I used to create the cluster:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --region $REGION \
    --zone $ZONE \
    --master-machine-type $MASTER_MACHINE_TYPE \
    --master-boot-disk-size $MASTER_DISK_SIZE \
    --worker-boot-disk-size $WORKER_DISK_SIZE \
    --num-workers=$NUM_WORKERS \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh \
    --metadata gcs-connector-version=$GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
    --metadata bigquery-connector-version=$BQ_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
    --scopes cloud-platform \
    --metadata JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:scipy:pandas:scikit-learn \
    --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
    --image-version=1.3
```

I need the BigQuery connector, GCS connector, Jupyter and DataLab for my cluster.

How can I keep my master node running? Thank you.

Comment: Does your project have any shared GCE startup scripts that might have some kind of auto-shutdown on idle logic? Are there any other GCE VMs in your project that are running any kind of reaper to shutdown other VMs that they think are idle? If you go to Stackdriver audit logs under "Compute Engine" and "activity" logs you should see records of what issued the shutdown commands; is it the compute engine default service account which issued those commands?

Comment: Yes, it's the default service account. (which listed under authenticationInfo of the log). However, there are other instances running on the same project, having the same service account, and is not shutting down automatically when idle. In addition, only the master node is stopped automatically, the worker nodes are running all the time..

Comment: I just tested initiating a cluster without any initialization-actions, under same project with same service account. It turns out that the cluster is up-running without automatically stops...

Comment: Probably due to Datalab's auto shutdown (default is 90min) https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown

Comment: Datalab uses the env var [`DATALAB_DISABLE_IDLE_TIMEOUT_PROCESS`](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/6f1a5b4877ee475406d5661c42dfcd6a60b582b9/sources/web/datalab/idleTimeout.ts#L35) to control auto-shutdown. Can you try running the Docker container with `-e "DATALAB_DISABLE_IDLE_TIMEOUT_PROCESS=true"`?

Comment: I'm aware of the DataLab idle timeout, but this is the DataLab that's installed in a cluster under DataProc. That option is not working for dataproc clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As summarized in the comment thread, this is indeed caused by Datalab's [auto-shutdown feature](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown). There are a couple ways to change this behavior:

1. Upon first creating the Datalab-enabled Dataproc cluster, log in to Datalab and click on the "Idle timeout in about ..." text to disable it: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown#disabling_the_auto_shutdown_timer - The text will change to "Idle timeout is disabled"
2. Edit the initialization action to set the environment variable as suggested by yelsayed:

   ```
   function run_datalab(){
     if docker run -d --restart always --net=host -e "DATALAB_DISABLE_IDLE_TIMEOUT_PROCESS=true" \
         -v "${DATALAB_DIR}:/content/datalab" ${VOLUME_FLAGS} datalab-pyspark; then
       echo 'Cloud Datalab Jupyter server successfully deployed.'
     else
       err 'Failed to run Cloud Datalab'
     fi
   }
   ```

And use your custom initialization action instead of the stock gs://dataproc-initialization-actions one. It could be worth filing a tracking issue in the github repo for dataproc initialization actions too, suggesting to disable the timeout by default or provide an easy metadata-based option. It's probably true that the auto-shutdown behavior isn't as expected in default usage on a Dataproc cluster since the master is also performing roles other than running the Datalab service.

Comment: Method 1 works, but it needs to be setup everytime manually. For method 2, I edited the initialization action as suggested. However, when I connected to DataLab, the setting still shows a 90m auto shutdown time rather than 0. Any suggestions of fixing method 2?

Comment: Hmm, when I tested with that init action the 90m shutdown disappeared for me. Is it possible you forgot to re-upload your edited init action to your own GCS bucket and/or pointed at a different version of it when creating your cluster? You can try my copy that I just added public read permissions: `gs://hadoop-cloud-dev-dhuo/datalab.sh` and/or just diff it against your own one to see the difference (don't depend on it long term though as I might delete my copy)

Comment: I downloaded your shell and it's identical to mine. However, I think I found the reason. I don't see the "Idle timeout in about ..." text when clicked the right upper corner icon; and I found that the master node is not shut down for 90 min. I was referring to the 'Auto Shutdown' textbox under 'Settings', that is still 90m. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Ah yes, that box still shows up, but it's fine to ignore. The main dropdown is the source of truth as to whether the shutdown is active. It seems the setting for "number of minutes before shutdown" is stored separately form the boolean for enabling the feature entirely, so in the modified init action we've just modified the boolean, while the numeric parameter is still being stored somewhere, just not used. Looks like the "update" button is also greyed out so it must know that the setting is disabled.

Comment: You could file this as a cosmetic bug in Datalab; they could make it less confusing in "settings" by having some text indicating that the feature is definitely disabled